# Google Drive App Not Downloading Files (MacOS)

Tags: macos, macbook, google-drive-for-desktop

I have a folder in my Windows PC that is synced with Google Drive. I downloaded the google drive app on my macbook, found the folder I was interested and selected "available offline". Instantly, several files started downloading. But after a few minutes this stopped. Now when I click on Google Drive's icon in the menu bar several items are on "Download queue" but nothing has been downloaded for 5 days now.

What is happening?

Comment: Are there any logs? What research have you done? Have you reviewed the client settings?

Comment: Hi, after re-installing the app it works fine. I don't really know what changed..

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP notes that reinstalling resolved the issue.